# Is it permissible to do namaz on bed on floor?

Tags: salat

I live in very tiny house n sleep on floor. I have a bed on floor made of up blanket and 2 sheets folded to make it soft. My question is if it is permissible to pray namaz on it? I found reference [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/96107)  but it is unclear how soft is too soft? Because blanket is made up of cotton or/and wool.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're referring to doing a normal namaz while effectively using the bed as a prayer mat? not doing a namaz while lying in bed, correct?

Comment: Correct @goldPseudo

Comment: You have be able to feel the ground with your forehead, or salah is invalid. I have been warned against using even a thick prayer mat, and to be extra careful when I do. I personally would not risk reading salah on the case you mention. Have you considered reading outdoors instead?

Answer (score 0):

Hi do do you put a prayer mat on the blankets?.. Knowledge I have is if you don't have space at all then maybe acceptable and if its paak